# Alert de sucesso para o usuário com Vue

Tags: vue.js

Eu tenho uma sessão na minha aplicação, onde o usuário desativa e ativa documentos, no momento que ele ativa ou desativa queria mostrar um alert de sucesso no padrão do vue.js, mas não sei como.

Logo a baixo tem o código ativa e desativa o documento, como eu faria para dar um alert na tela para o usuário que a operação de ATIVAR ou DESATIVAR deu certo?

```
methods: {
  handleDesactive() {
    if ( this.typeShow != 6 ) {
      axios.get(`/atas/${this.id}/desativar`)
        .then( res => eventHub.$emit('removeCard', this.id) );
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    } else {
      axios.get(`/atas/${this.id}/ativar`)
        .then( res => eventHub.$emit('removeCard', this.id) );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Utilize `.then( () => alert("Deu certo") )` quanto utilizar o `axios`

Comment: Beleza
`then( res => eventHub.$emit('removeCard', this.id) => alert("Deu certo")` assim?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/kecefiwoka.js

Comment: Tem nada nesse hastebin

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qDVJD8XS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
axios.get(`/atas/${this.id}/ativar`)
  .then((res) => {
    eventHub.$emit('removeCard', this.id);
    alert('Deu certo');
  });
```